# Reformat \frac depending on numerator/denominator size difference

Tags: fractions

Is it possible to detect cases where the second argument of `\frac` is much smaller than the first argument, and split it?  Namely (I'm using a new macro name `\wfrac` to simplify things),

```
\wfrac{x}{2} % => \frac{x}{2}
\wfrac{x+y}{2} % => \frac{1}{2}\left(x+y\right)
\wfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3}{x+y+z+t}
% => \frac{1}{x+y+z+t} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3\right)
% => or \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3\right) / \left(x+y+z+t\right)
\wfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i}
% => \frac{...}{...} (unchanged)
```

Feel free to tell me that this is a bad idea.

**EDIT:** As David notes in his comment, it is not clear what I define as bigger/smaller.  The third example in particular features a case where the numerator is taller, but the denominator is wider.  he also notes that `\wfrac{x}{y}` could become `(x)/(y)`.  I am building the requirements as I write the question, so feel free to tweak them at your will.

`\wfrac{x}{y}` should become one of `\frac{x}{y}`, or `\frac{1}{y}(x)`, or `(x)/(y)`, with `()/` scaling as appropriate.  Here is one scheme that could give nice results.  Denote `hx`, `hy` the heights (plus depths) of `x` and `y`; `wx`, `wy` their widths; `h0` and `w0` customizable thresholds for what is considered "small", for instance the dimensions of the formula `$a+b$`, but probably the threshold should depend on the `\mathstyle`.

1. If `hy < h0` and `wy < w0`,

   1. If `hx < h0` and `wx < max(w0, 2 * wy)`, use `\frac{x}{y}`.
   2. Otherwise use `\frac{1}{y}(x)`.
2. Otherwise use `(x)/(y)`.

Comment: Is there something wrong with simply boxing up the top and bottom and then measuring them?

Comment: Hmm, seems useful, maybe it can be merged into `xfrac` if possible. How about put the two args into boxes and measure them?

Comment: What's the criterion for "much smaller"? In the third example with cm fonts and textsyle setting, the denominator is _wider_ than the numerator but you still split. (If splitting because something is big I think I'd favour changing to `(#1)/(#2)` rather than `\frac{1}{#2}(#1)` as it avoids cramping either argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I tried to clarify my mind.  Admittedly this is still not a good question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the new title, I updated it somewhat toward what you propose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I though this was an interesting question, so I gave it a try.
Let me start off with the result:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wfrac}

\begin{document}
\setmaxeq{a+b} % Reference equation for size

\[ \wfrac{x}{2} \]
\[ \wfrac{x+y}{2} \]
\[ \wfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3}{x+y+z+t} \]
\[ \wfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i} \]

\setmax{34pt}{10pt} % Manual maximum size

\[ \wfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} i} \]

\setmaxeq{x} % Reference equation again

\[ \wfrac{x}{x} \]
\[ \efrac{x}{x} \]
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:

[image: result]

### Options:

- `text`:    compare to the equation in `\textstyle`.
- `display`: compare to the equation in `\displaystyle`.
- `none`:    compare to the equation in whatever style is currently active.
- `noparen`: no parentheses
- `small`:   small maximum height and width
- `big`:     big maximum height and width
- `huge`:    huge maximum height and width
- `lparen`:  set left paren, eg: `lparen=\left[`
- `rparen`:  set right paren, eg: `rparen={\right]}`
- `div`:     set division mark, eg: `div=\div`

### Commands

1. `\wfrac`:    fraction following 'less' rules.
2. `\efrac`:    fraction following 'less or equal' rules.
3. `\setmax`:   set the maximum size.
4. `\setmaxeq`: set the maximum size using a reference equation.
5. `\getmax`:   get the maximum size.
6. `\getsize`:  get the size from an equation.
7. `\setparen`: set the parentheses, takes two arguments.
8. `\setdiv`:   set the division mark.

And here is `wfrac.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{wfrac}[2012/11/03 v1.01 intelligent fractions]

% Lengths and widths
\newdimen \wfrac@hx
\newdimen \wfrac@hy
\newdimen \wfrac@hmax
\newdimen \wfrac@wx
\newdimen \wfrac@wy
\newdimen \wfrac@wmax
\newdimen \wfrac@wmaxcalc

% Parenthesis and division mark
\newcommand*{\wfrac@lparen}{\left(}
\newcommand*{\wfrac@rparen}{\right)}
\newcommand*{\wfrac@div}{\middle/}

% Options
\IfFileExists{xkeyval.sty}{
    \RequirePackage{xkeyval}
    \DeclareOptionX{lparen}{\renewcommand*{\wfrac@lparen}{##1}}
    \DeclareOptionX{rparen}{\renewcommand*{\wfrac@rparen}{##1}}
    \DeclareOptionX{div}{\renewcommand*{\wfrac@div}{##1}}
}{
    \let\DeclareOptionX\DeclareOption
    \let\ExecuteOptionsX\ExecuteOptions
    \let\ProcessOptionsX\ProcessOptions
}

\DeclareOptionX{text}{\edef\wfrac@style{\textstyle}}
\DeclareOptionX{display}{\edef\wfrac@style{\displaystyle}}
\DeclareOptionX{none}{\edef\wfrac@style{}}
\DeclareOptionX{noparen}{\renewcommand*{\wfrac@lparen}{}\renewcommand*{\wfrac@rparen}{}}
\DeclareOptionX{small}{\wfrac@wmax = 25pt \wfrac@hmax = 10pt}
\DeclareOptionX{big}{\wfrac@wmax = 50pt \wfrac@hmax = 50pt}
\DeclareOptionX{huge}{\wfrac@wmax = 100pt \wfrac@hmax = 100pt}
\ExecuteOptionsX{text,small}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax

% Fraction variations
\newcommand*{\wfrac@Afrac}[2]{\left. \wfrac@lparen #1 \wfrac@rparen \wfrac@div \wfrac@lparen #2 \wfrac@rparen \right.}
\newcommand*{\wfrac@Bfrac}[2]{\frac{1}{#2}\wfrac@lparen #1 \wfrac@rparen}
\newcommand*{\wfrac@Cfrac}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}

% Main commands
\newcommand*\setparen[2]{
    \renewcommand*{\wfrac@lparen}{#1}
    \renewcommand*{\wfrac@rparen}{#2}
}

\newcommand*\setdiv[1]{
    \renewcommand*{\wfrac@div}{#1}
}

\newcommand*\setmax[2]{
    \wfrac@wmax = #1
    \wfrac@hmax = #2
}

\newcommand*\setmaxeq[1]{
    \settowidth{\wfrac@wmax}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \settoheight{\wfrac@hmax}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
}

\newcommand*\getmax{
    \the\wfrac@wmax $\times$ \the\wfrac@hmax
}

\newcommand*\getsize[1]{
    \settowidth{\wfrac@wx}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \settoheight{\wfrac@hx}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \the\wfrac@wx $\times$ \the\wfrac@hx
}

\newcommand*\wfrac[2]{
    \settowidth{\wfrac@wx}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \settowidth{\wfrac@wy}{$ \wfrac@style #2 $}
    \settoheight{\wfrac@hx}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \settoheight{\wfrac@hy}{$ \wfrac@style #2 $}    
    % max(w0, 2 * wy)
    \ifdim \wfrac@wmax < 2\wfrac@wy
        \wfrac@wmaxcalc = 2\wfrac@wy
    \else
        \wfrac@wmaxcalc = \wfrac@wmax
    \fi
    %
    \ifdim \wfrac@hy < \wfrac@hmax
        \ifdim \wfrac@wy < \wfrac@wmax
            \ifdim \wfrac@hx < \wfrac@hmax
                \ifdim \wfrac@wx < \wfrac@wmaxcalc
                    \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Cfrac
                \else
                    \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Bfrac
                \fi
            \else
                \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Bfrac
            \fi 
        \else
            \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Afrac
        \fi
    \else
        \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Afrac
    \fi
    %
    \wfrac@frac{#1}{#2}
}

\newcommand*\efrac[2]{
    \settowidth{\wfrac@wx}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \settowidth{\wfrac@wy}{$ \wfrac@style #2 $}
    \settoheight{\wfrac@hx}{$ \wfrac@style #1 $}
    \settoheight{\wfrac@hy}{$ \wfrac@style #2 $}    
    % max(w0, 2 * wy)
    \ifdim \wfrac@wmax < 2\wfrac@wy
        \wfrac@wmaxcalc = 2\wfrac@wy
    \else
        \wfrac@wmaxcalc = \wfrac@wmax
    \fi
    %
    \ifdim \wfrac@hy > \wfrac@hmax
        \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Afrac
    \else
        \ifdim \wfrac@wy > \wfrac@wmax
            \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Afrac
        \else
            \ifdim \wfrac@hx > \wfrac@hmax
                \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Bfrac
            \else
                \ifdim \wfrac@wx > \wfrac@wmaxcalc
                    \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Bfrac
                \else
                    \let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Cfrac
                \fi
            \fi 
        \fi
    \fi
    %
    \wfrac@frac{#1}{#2}
}

\endinput
```

Comment: Nice!  It might be better to define `\newcommand*{\wfrac@Afrac}[2]{\left.\left(#1\right)\middle/\left(#2\right)\right.}`, `\newcommand*{\wfrac@Bfrac}[2]{\frac{1}{#2}\left(#1\right)`, and `\newcommand*{\wfrac@Cfrac}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}`, and in the nested conditionals use `\let\wfrac@frac=\wfrac@Afrac` (or Bfrac, Cfrac...), and outside the conditionals call `\wfrac@frac{#1}{#2}`.  This is a bit safer to allow for arbitrary arguments `#1` and `#2`.  Also, it would be nice to provide a variant which does not add parentheses in the A and B forms, but I am not sure what syntax is best.

Comment: Great suggestions! I've added a new version of `wfrac.sty`. It includes the `\setparen{...}{...}` and `\setdiv{...}` commands to change the parentheses and division mark. I've also added options: `text`, `display`, `none`, `noparen`, `small`, `big`, `huge`, `lparen`, `rparen` and `div`.

Comment: It would be even nicer to control the presence of absence of parentheses for the numerator and denominator of each fraction independently: I am thinking of the case where a numerator or denominator is a single object.  For instance, `\wfrac[paren = num]{x+y}{e^{i\pi xyz}}` could give `(x+y)/e^{i\pi xyz}`.  The values of the `paren` option would be `num`, `denom`, `none`, `both` or variants of that.  That is actually not enough for cases like `\wfrac{\sum_j x_j}{y}`, for which correct forms are `\frac{#1}{#2}`, `(#1)/#2`, and `\frac{1}{#2}#1`, with parentheses or not around `#1`.